How to Save a DateTime Field with Default Time 00:00:00 in Laravel Voyager
I'm using Laravel Voyager to manage my database records. I have a BREAD setup for a model that includes a datetime field. I want to ensure that when a date is selected, it is saved in the database with the time set to 00:00:00 and 23:59:59.
I added the following JSON to the details of the datetime_from and datetime_to field in BREAD:
{
    "format": "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"
}

{
    "format": "%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59"
}


However, this only affects the display format in the admin panel and does not actually save the time as 00:00:00 / 23:59:59 in the database. The time being saved is the one selected in the datetime picker, which is very inconvenient..
How can I ensure that the datetime field is always saved with the time set to 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 ?
